# url parameter in .ajax() function jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I found this example in the Web, about how is the communication between Jquery - Json - PHP, and there is very good explained the several Options like `.$ajax()` or `$.post()`

But in the Parameter URL of all cases they Show this:   url:'c=Prozess&a=NPvonProzess'

```
$.ajax({
                    data: { num : 1},
                    url:   **'?c=Prozess&a=NPvonProzess',**
                    type:  'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    beforeSend: function (){
                        alert("Wird gesendt");
                    },
                    success:  function () {
                        alert("Wurde gesendet");
                        })
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert('Fehler');
                    }
                });
```

And nobody is explaining what this means. Maybe is very obvious but I am very new in this subject and´is a Little difficult for me to understand :) .

Can somebody be so Kind and help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See:

```
?c=Prozess&a=NPvonProzess
```

This is used to call query string which have some keys and respective value to it. So you can simplify it like:

```
c = Prozess
a = NPvonProzess
```

you can see param key `c` has the value of `Prozess` and `a` has the value of `NPvonProzess`.

If we take `$.ajax()` method of jQuery then you can even send it with `data:{}` like this:

```
$.ajax({
    data: { num : 1, c : Prozess, a : NPvonProzess},
    url:   theurl,
});
```

or if you are dealing with form submit then you can make use of `.serialize()` method:

```
data: $('#formID').serialize(),
```

---

Another thing i want to mention that if you just use form with a server side like php then if you submit your filled form to the specified action url then you can see there is a generated query string by the form submission. That might look like this:

Suppose this is the url of your form `http://localhost/index.html` and you have an action set to form to the php file named `form.php` then if you submit the form then the url will change to `http://localhost/form.php?user=xyz&age=35&gender=male`.

In this url:

```
http://localhost/form.php?user=xyz&age=35&gender=male
```

the params say that a form has been submit, which looks like this:

```
<form action='form.php' method='get'>
    <input type='text' name='user' value=''><br>
    <input type='number' name='age' value=''><br>
    <input type='radio' name='user' value='male'>
    <input type='radio' name='user' value='female'><br>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the URL you are submitting the AJAX request to.

In those examples it is submitting to the same page.

You can leave the URL params out, `url:   '/site-folder/form-submit.php',`

Or if you leave it blank and it will submit to the same page.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/